# Deploy Laravel Project on Dreamhost but not working

Tags: php, laravel, server, dreamhost

I have uploaded all files in dreamhost server and also point our domain to public directory. But when I open website it is showing site not found. Below is website link.

https://laraveleqn.samiflabs.com/

I have direct uploaded all files from local xampp, in that it is working fine..so should I execute all command like key:generate, composer install again ?

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Samif, There is not any specific reason to solve the kind of error
> but some conclusion for solve the error.
>
> - First you can check .env file in your server.
> - composer install and clear cache via
>
>   - php artisan config:cache
>   - php artisan config:clear
>   - php artisan cache:clear
> - And finally not solved then try to Dump and Die on index.php in public folder

Comment: thanks for reply..I tried but still site not found error coming..can you tell me what to write in index.php to call dd..I think even index.php is not calling..any comments on this.

Comment: Welcome Samif, You can put like dd('testing...'). If the message will display in browser then we'll sure the issue in your code, not in hosting process.

Comment: Thanks..yes it was hosting issue..now it is solved and website working fine..many thanks for your help..